# How to create a self signed certificate with the private key inside in a file in one simple step?

Tags: security, certificate

I'd like to generate a certificate for development purposes, but I don't want to install the certificate in the store.

`makecert` with the switch `-pe` doesn't create the private key if you specify an output file.

When I tried to create a `.pfx` file by exporting the certificate created with `makecert`, it asks for a password to protect the private key; I guess I can't use it with my WCF service since the config file has no information about the password...

Why in the hell is it so complicated? Do you know a simple tool to create a certificate with private key inside a file without password in one simple step?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=CompanyXYZ Server" -b 01/01/2007 -e 01/01/2010 -sky exchange Server.cer -sv Server.pvk
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk Server.pvk -spc Server.cer -pfx Server.pfx
```

from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/wcfcertificates.aspx).

Comment: This works great with one caveat. For me (6 years later, running VS2013), if I supply a password to the dialogs that come up, the pfx file seems to have no password (and I get a password-related security exception when using the pfx file in the C# X509Certificate2() method. I have to usethe -pi and -po switches on  pvk2pfk.exe, even though the docs say it will default to using the given password.

Comment: @bitcoder Can you put here your command? If you still have it. ;)

Comment: @Jenan I _think_ I used this in another answer here hopefully it is the thing you need (and the rest of the discussion there may be useful to you if you are using some of the C# apis with your cert): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654056/guidance-on-thinktecture-identityserver-v3-certificates/31977847#31977847