# The certificate 'CN=ds.com' must have a private key. The process must have access rights for the private key

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, certificate, makecert

*After searching a lot and trying other's answers, every solution -  still without success*

> *Short preface : response request from my machine to itself - does work with certificate. From  another computer to  my machine - it doesn't.*

In my machine- I've created 2 certificates : public key and private key via  :

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=ds.com" -b 01/01/2018 -e 01/01/2020 
-sky exchange Server.cer -sv Server.pvk
```

And then :

```
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk Server.pvk -spc Server.cer -pfx Server.pfx
```

(taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1690143/859154))

I've installed them *both* in the store in my machine(via mmc) :

[image]

I'm using this simple [WCF config](https://gist.github.com/RoyiNamir/284ed2ebdf6ebf745d803e4200f40364) which I host  in WAS IIS at **my** machine.

When I call that service (from my  machine to itself) with this simple code:

```
  WSHttpBinding myBinding = new WSHttpBinding();
            myBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
            myBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType =MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
            EndpointAddress ea = new
                EndpointAddress("http://ds.com/Service1.svc/HelloWorldService");

            var client   = new HelloWorldServiceClient(myBinding, ea);

            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                StoreName.Root,
                X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                "9394f570069e7af263ef7ca5a46a5bcab9f68659");
    Console.WriteLine(client.GetMessage("Mike Liu"));
    Console.ReadLine();
    client.Close();
```

— I DO get result :

[image]

*Great.*

Now let's go to **another** computer which  I've installed in *only* the public key certificate into the trusted root.

However - now when I access **my** computer (with the same code ^) - I get the following error:

> The certificate 'CN=ds.com' must have a private key. The process must
>   have access rights for the private key.

Even if I shutdown the WAS IIS service at my computer , I still see the error at the other machine.

It seems that the problem is only at the other machine. I've already set permission in the other machine:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto <--------Everyone: full control +inheritance
```

**Question:**

What am I missing here ? Why does it look for a private key in the client machine. It is not supposed to have the private key. The private should only reside in the service computer. (which is my machine).

[**Full stack trace image (at the other machine)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGgBD.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are using the same certificate on server and client. That is not what it should be.

In order to secure client request, you have to sign request with client certificate and server response is signed with server certificate.

So on client you should have:

- private (and public) key of client certificate in it's personal certificate store
- public key of server certificate within trusted root authorities

On server you should have the oposite:

- private (and public) key of server certificate in it's personal certificate store
- public key of client certificate within trusted root authorities

You can see example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/message-security-certificate) and read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-certificate-client).

Details about the HTTPS protocol are very nicely described in this [article](https://robertheaton.com/2014/03/27/how-does-https-actually-work/).

Comment: Thanks for replying  - To my understanding ( possibly wrong) , the server should have public and private certificaes. While users should only have public. and they can encrypt data , which only the Private key can open. No ? If so - I don't understand why clients around the world should have private key.

Comment: In communication between client and server you have both request and response. Request from client is encrypted with server public key and decrypted with server private key on server. Response from server is encrypted with client public key and decrypted on client with client private key. 

So yes you need both.

Comment: Hi. You said "_Details about the HTTPS_" - but my code uses `EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("http://ds.com/Service1.svc/HelloWorldService");` ( not HTTPS). So how come it works ? Also - Does the ` client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate` code is for the encryption of the message or for decryption - when response is back  from server ?

Comment: I wasn't really paying attention on that. You are using `SecurityMode.Message`. That means message is encrypted and not the transport layer (HTTPS). Still theory on public/private keys and encritption is the same. 

You can see differences of WCF security modes in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673283/wcf-transport-vs-message).

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to 2 possible reasons.

1. no private key avaialble in certificate current user store (personal/trusted people)
2. IIS application pool do not have access of private key for (current user store)

enable wcf trace and you will find error in log mentioned in image.

[image]

for 1) install private key (pfx)
for 2nd provide identity in application pool as given in below image.
[image]